# What does {... player} mean in react?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to make a list with react, and from random site I found

```
        players.map((player) => (
          <PlayerItem
            key={player.id}
            id={player.id}
            {...player} />
        ))
```

Also, I have the players list, but I don't know what the `{... }` means, maybe someone can explain the meanings?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: The JavaScript spread operator (...) allows us to quickly copy all or part of an existing array or object into another array or object. https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_es6_spread.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a React specific feature, but JS in general, and called `spread`.
Let's assume you have a player object that looks like:

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: "player"
   url: "https://...."
}
```

writing:

```
<PlayerItem {...player} />
```

is the equivalent of writing

```
<PlayerItem id={player.id} name={player.name} url={player.url} />
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you pass all the properties in the `player` object as props to the `PlayerItem`.

If `player` is like below:

```
let player = { name: "pqr", data: "abc"}
```

Then it's the same as the following:

```
<PlayerItem
    key={player.id}
    id={player.id}
    name={player.name} 
    data={player.data}
/>
```

It's a short-hand way that saves time as you don't need to care separately about each property.

See [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

{...player} - looks like javascript spread operator. In react is easy way to automatically apply all the props

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is mozilla documentation about spread operators

Answer (score 0):

Basically `...` is called as the spread operator in javascript. It basically expands an iterable object (in your case the 'players' list)

```
function sum(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + z;
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

// Function 1
console.log(sum(...numbers));
// expected output: 6


// Function 2
console.log(sum(numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2]));
// expected output: 6
```

in the above example, Function 1 is written using the spread syntax.